# Error in set list in UPDATE clause. Unable to parse query text

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access, error-handling

I have an update table query in asp.net c# when i run it it is giving an error: Error in set list in UPDATE clause.
Unable to parse query text.

the code is as follows:

```
UPDATE HolidaysList  
SET Holiday = 'Vijaya Dashmi', 
    Date = '10/11/2016 12:00:00 AM', 
    Day = 'Tuesdayy', 
    Month = 'October' 
where SlNo = '10'
```

Comment: `Date` is a reserved keyword, try `"Date"`. Same goes for `Day` and `Month`

Comment: Also, If I remember correctly, ms-access requires date values to be wrapped in `#`, not `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the date in **YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss** format.

**Also, the column name you are using is a type: Date column.** I have modified it to DateColumn. You can change it to your respective column name.

So your query would now be:

```
UPDATE HolidaysList  SET Holiday = 'Vijaya Dashmi', DateColumn = '2016/10/11 12:00:00 AM', Day = 'Tuesdayy', Month = 'October' where SlNo = '10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` for column name

```
UPDATE [HolidaysList]  SET [Holiday] = 'Vijaya Dashmi', [Date] = '10/11/2016 12:00:00 AM', [Day] = 'Tuesdayy', [Month] = 'October' where [SlNo] = '10'
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Avoid using reserved words for field names. It's bad practice. Also as pointed out above that won't work if the [Date] (sic) field is a date data type. You would still need # delimiters around it `[Date] = #2016/10/11 12:00:00 AM#`